# How do I delete record from a single table in a query with many joins and a condition?

Tags: mysql

Having the following related tables

[image]

I need to eliminate the relationships between `table4` and `table1`, that is, the data that exists in `table1_table4` with the condition that table4's `target` is different from table3's `target`

To identify the number of affected rows I wrote this query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table2
        INNER JOIN
    table2_table3 ON table2.id = table2_table3.table2_id
        INNER JOIN
    table3 ON table3.id = table2_table3.table3_id
        INNER JOIN
    table1_table2 ON table2.id = table1_table2.table2_id
        INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table1.id = table1_table2.table1_id
        INNER JOIN
    table1_table4 ON table1.id = table1_table4.table1_id
        INNER JOIN
    table4 ON table4.id = table1_table4.table4_id
WHERE
    table3.target != table4.target;
```

Here I identify 149 records to be affected.

Now I need to delete the affected data in `table1_table4`. Could you please advise me how should I write this deletion query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same join as in your select

```
    DELETE t2.* 
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN
        table2_table3 ON table2.id = table2_table3.table2_id
            INNER JOIN
        table3 ON table3.id = table2_table3.table3_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1_table2 ON table2.id = table1_table2.table2_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1 ON table1.id = table1_table2.table1_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1_table4 ON table1.id = table1_table4.table1_id
            INNER JOIN
        table4 ON table4.id = table1_table4.table4_id
    WHERE     table3.target != table4.target;
```

and for table1_table4 , if the join conditions are the same, you could use

```
    DELETE table1_table4.*
    FROM table1_table4 
    INNER JOIN
        table2_table3 ON table2.id = table2_table3.table2_id
            INNER JOIN
        table3 ON table3.id = table2_table3.table3_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1_table2 ON table2.id = table1_table2.table2_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1 ON table1.id = table1_table2.table1_id
            INNER JOIN
        table1_table4 ON table1.id = table1_table4.table1_id
            INNER JOIN
        table4 ON table4.id = table1_table4.table4_id
    WHERE     table3.target != table4.target;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I need to delete from `table1_table4`. Do I need to move `table1_table4` `INNER JOIN` reference to the begin of `FROM` clause?

Comment: answer  updated .. for table4  ( make a safe copy of your data test before try to delete)

Comment: In your answer I see you are removing data from `table2` and `table4` but what I need is to remove the data in `table1_table4`

Comment: anyway the rule for delete  is based  or the same from and join conditio for the select  .. and  the clause delete tablename.* from

Comment: Interestingly the deletion query affected 119 records, when the query selection shows 149 records. Even more curious is that once the records have been deleted, I execute the selection query, return 1 and wait for 30. Some suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean with  "the selection query, return 1 and wait for 30"  ? (wait for 30?)   explain better  ..    .. remember that you are deleting only  the table   table1_table4.. could be that some of the rows  in this table hane more then on row join in others  tables ..

Answer (score 1):

Mysql supports multicolumn IN

```
delete from table1_table4 where (table1_id, table4_id) in (
 select t14.table1_id, t14.table4_id from
    table2
    INNER JOIN
    table2_table3 ON table2.id = table2_table3.table2_id
    INNER JOIN
    table3 ON table3.id = table2_table3.table3_id
    INNER JOIN
    table1_table2 ON table2.id = table1_table2.table2_id
    INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table1.id = table1_table2.table1_id
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table1_table4) t14 ON table1.id = t14.table1_id
    INNER JOIN
    table4 ON table4.id = t14.table4_id
)
```

I'm not a huge fan of using IN for long lists, but this is relatively short

You'll also notice that your table1_table4 is wrapped in another select. This is a fudge to get past the restriction that MySQL doesn't let you modify a table you selected from. This subquery materialises the table as a temporary one, so mySQL sees it as a different table from the one you're updating. As a trick it probably won't work in MySQL 8 - see the link posted in the first comment for more info

Comment: This won't work because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; i've "fixed" that, but please leave your comment as i reference it in the question

Comment: I just tried your query, I am experimenting the same behavior scaisEdge query, the delete query affect 119 records, but my count query in the question count 149 rows, Any idea why I am getting this result? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate rows? `DELETE FROM table WHERE (a,b) IN (1,2),(1,2)` will only delete one row even though there are two in the IN.. (if a,b is the primary key of course). Try doing `SELECT DISTINCT table1_table4.*` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` in your 149 rows query, and see if it still give 149 rows